# boxing of loops and if-statements

Tags: java

This code example should print out the text "will never be printed" about one second after the application was started, but how the text says this does never happen.

Maybe it is because of the possible incorrect boxing of my blocks, but I don't think that is the reason.

```
class ThreadTest
{
    public static boolean b = false;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        new Thread(){
            @Override public void run(){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(Exception e){}

                b = true;
            }
        }.start();


        while(true)
            if(b)
            {
                System.out.println("will never be printed");
                break;
            }
}
```

}

Please say if this is really very crazy or if I simply make a big fault.

It looks like nobody read the question. The problem is that The line "will never be printed should be printed after one second but it isn't". You are all only writing things which have simply nothing to do with this question.
Again: why isnt this line Executed ?!!!! :

```
System.out.println("will never be printed");
```

Comment: Without `{}`, only one statement (end of `;`) is considered part of the construct/block. Also, you could've tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference , but the second one is more clear

Answer (score 1):

In this case they're equal. But the later is preferable for readability.

```
if(a)
   while(b)
     if(c) {

     }
```

Is like:

```
if(a) {
    while(b) {
      if(c) {

     }
   }
}
```

**BUT**

```
if(a)
   blabla;
   while(b)
     if(c) {

     }
```

Is **not** like:

```
if(a) {
   blabla;
   while(b)
     if(c) {

     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They both are equal in this case but we prefer to use braces even if the conditional statement has only single statement to avoid some debugging problems which can occur with very small mistakes.

Your first code equals the second by this way.

```
top:
while(true)  // Had only one if statement
    if(...)  // Had only one while statement
        while(...)  // Had only one if statement
            if(...)  // It can have more code since it uses braces
            {
                //code
                break top;
            }
```

And since the compiler auto-adds the braces on compilation, it would become on decompilation as your second code.

Answer (score 0):

the two cases are the same, but that wouldn't be the case if you had, for example:

```
top:
while(true)
    if(...)
        while(...)
            if(...)
            {
                //code
                break top;
            }
        //more code
```

in compare with

```
top:
while(true)
{
    if(...)
    {
        while(...)
        {
            if(...)
            {
                //code
                break top;
            }
        }

        // more code
    }
}
```

of course as everyone said, the second one is also clearer. i would advise always to use the "{" and "}" in a line of their own, in the same column as the statement that opened them

for example:

like that

```
if(condition)
{
   //code
}
```

not

```
if(condition){
  code
}
```

and defiantly not

```
   if(condition)
   {
     // code
}
```